# shift of rows among matrices matlab

Tags: matlab, rows, shift

I am doing a project on Particle Swarm optimization, coding in Matlab. I need to replace the rows of matrix A by some of the rows from matrix B and remove those rows from matrix B as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put you row indices in vectors, say

```
indexA=[0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0].
indexB=[0 1 0 1 0 1].
```

Partition B into

```
A(indexA,:) = B(indexB,:);
B(indexB,:) = [];
```

Comment: You don't need the `B1` or `B2` buffers btw. You can do `A(indexA,:) = B(indexB,:); B(indexB,:) = []`;

Comment: I also don't think using logical indexing here is the best. I'd probably use `indexA = [4 6 7]` and `indexB = [2 4 6]` to make it clear that they are the same length. But that's just me.